# constant animation speed CSS

Tags: css

i have an animation and i want to make the animation do the same move on all the transition, on what i have the animation begin fast and almost on the end begins to slow down.

```css
#tableNews {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width:90%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 15s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 15s infinite;
}    
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 60px;}
    to {top: -200px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 60px;}
    to {top: -200px;}
}
```

```html
<table id="tableNews" class="TableList" border="0" width="100%" style="overflow:hidden;">
<tbody>                                                      
  <tr class="new-separator">                                                            
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#"></a><hr></td>
        </tr>
                                                                   
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML. What kind of element is `#tableNews`? It also depends on the element type. `:)`

Comment: You mean a linear timing function? Just put [`linear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) between `15s` and `infinite`.

Comment: Is your snippet working? `:P`

Comment: sorry the delate, yes its working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it is making an `ease`. If you give an option `linear`, which is the animation's [timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function), that works with constant speed and no delay. Let's do this way:

```css
#tableNews {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width:90%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 15s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 15s linear infinite;
}    
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 60px;}
    to {top: -200px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 60px;}
    to {top: -200px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="tableNews">Hi</div>
```

Comment: Ha ha... The `animation` itself is still noob buddy. Don't worry @portal47! `:)` Glad it helped you. `:D`

Comment: Check this out for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function