# Is it possible to make css animations "plain"?

Tags: javascript, css

I´m sorry, I have no idea how to explain this, so i'm just going to give an example:

```
.MovingDiv {
    position: fixed
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: MovingAnimation 5s;
}

@keyframes MovingAnimation {
    0% {left: 0px;}
    100% {left: 1000px;}
}
```

When this css code is used, the object moves from the left side of the screen to the right but i noticed that it starts out slow in the beginning, has a normal speed midway and slows down again at the end. Is there a way that I can maybe, with a little Javascript, make the animation "plain" as in have a constant speed from the beginning to the end?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772654/constant-animation-speed-css) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying an **[animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function)**. A setting of `linear` would probably be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try `transition-timing-function: linear` under `.movingDiv`